# What's faster in Python: searching elements of a set or searching for a pattern in a string?

Tags: python

I'm writing a bot that analyzes recently made reddit comments and I am trying to increase the speed that it takes to process a single comment. The bot will cycle through 500 comments then repeat the process with another 500 after a certain waiting period. Undoubtedly, some of these comments will be repeated, so I have a cache of comment id's that the bot can check with. I understand that this can be expensive in time, especially as the cache increases in size (adding ~500 entities each cycle), so I was wondering where I should put the scan.

In the part of the code I am currently looking at, there are two ways a comment can be disqualified and skipped: either it's id was found in the cache:

```
if getCommentLink(comment) in completedComments:
    addToLog("[Error 101] " + str(datetime.datetime.now().time()) + " comment already in cache",False)
else:
    ...
```

Or it does not contain the string pattern I am looking for:

```
begOfBotCallFound = botCallFormatBeg.lower() in commentText
endOfBotCallFound = botCallFormatEnd.lower() in commentText
if begOfBotCallFound == True and endOfBotCallFound == True:
    botCallInGoodFormat = (commentText.index(botCallFormatBeg.lower()) + len(botCallFormatBeg) + minimumCharsBetweenBegAndEnd) < commentText.index(botCallFormatEnd.lower())
    if botCallInGoodFormat == True:
        foundRequest = True
if foundRequest == False:
    addToLog(str(datetime.datetime.now().time()) + " failed request search - beginning found: " + str(begOfBotCallFound) + ", end found: " + str(endOfBotCallFound) + ", good format: " + str(botCallInGoodFormat),False)
else:
    ...
```

I understand that I could probably use a regex in the latter statement but I'm trying to avoid it unless I'm sure it will process faster (I'm not too skilled with regex).

After testing, using the cache check first then the string search yields around 1.8 seconds per post. Doing the reverse yields anywhere from 1.4-2.3 seconds per post (which probably varies based on how long the comment is). My worry is that as the cache increases in size, it may be more desirable to do the latter method.

My question is, at what point will searching through the cache as I am currently doing be slower than searching for string patterns in variable length comments? How large does my cache list have to be in order for this to be the case (not looking for a specific number)?

Comment: I feel that a cache check for comment ids should be very, very fast. What are you using to to store comment ids, a set? If it's a list, I would use a more appropriate data structure like a set or a hash.

Comment: Yes, the cache completedComments is a set

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity   ```x in s``` is faster for the set.  ```x in s``` for a string should be the same as a list.

Comment: Great resource. Thanks!

Comment: There are some more performance improvements that you can do, i.e., you don't need to do check no 2 (end of string) if check no 1 fails, but you evaluate it beforehand. Also, you do the lower() invocation multiple times. Since the lower() calls are irrelevant for length and index, you may want to avoid them. I realize that doesn't answer your question but in regards to that, there is the simple fact of measuring means knowing :)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll implement those improvements as well